# Contour plot from scattered data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, contour, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a 2D and 3D contour from x, y, z data. Does anyone know any good JavaScript library that does that?

Thank you

Comment: See [d3: Contour or Surface plot from Irregular/Scattered Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44662862/195835)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to another question that was already asked and answered at [Create contour map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964515/create-contour-map)

In that post, it was recommended to use d3.js and conrec.js.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: The OP states "scattered", i.e. irregular data. This makes it different from that earlier post in which the data was already on a uniform grid.  The means to interpolate irregular data onto a regular grid for use with d3.js and conrec.js is the crux of the issue.